# css button position not working in all browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I am coding a new website with a login feature, but the login button freaks out across the different browsers. Here is what I mean:

**Normal state - Firefox:**

[image: Firefox]

**Safari:**

[image: Safari]

**Chrome:**

[image: Chrome]

Here is the code for the form:

```
.log_in {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.log_in {
    display: inline-block;
}
.log_in input[type="button"] {
    background-color: #03586a;
    height: 26px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    width: 70px;
    line-height:normal !important;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
.log_in input[type="button"]:hover {
    background-color: #4c829c;
}
.log_in input[type="text"], .log_in input[type="password"] {
    width: 130px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #a1b5c4;
    line-height:normal !important;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #327d89;
}
.log_in input[type="text"]:hover, .log_in input[type="password"]:hover {
    background-color: #cfd8e0;
}
.log_in input[type="text"]:focus, .log_in input[type="password"]:focus {
    background-color: #cfd8e0;
}
```

How can I fix this to make it look like Firefox across all browsers?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzA3T/)**

Comment: Can you post the HTML and a fiddle

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)? Also, please show us your HTML.

Comment: I added the JS fiddle

Comment: looks like you based on `margin-top` to control the position of an **absolutely positioned** element, which is not enough, you have to use `top` and `left` attribute.

Comment: I tried using `top` now but it doesnt help with the position of the button

Comment: remove float style of the button,  make all input elements inline-block will be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the float of button, and all input are inline-block

```
.login input{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jzA3T/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change this css

```
.log_in input[type="button"] 
{
    background-color: #03586a;
    height: 26px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    width: 70px;
    line-height:normal !important;
}
```

Your button will be shown at right place. I checked in chrome but i hope i will work in all major browser.